# Problem with date_select on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following controller:

```
  def personalization
    @title = t "generic.forms.personalization"
  end

  def update_personalization
    begin
      @user.user_data.birthdate = Date.civil(params[:user_data][:"birthdate(1i)"].to_i,params[:user_data][:"birthdate(2i)"].to_i,params[:user_data][:"birthdate(3i)"].to_i)
    rescue
      wrong_data = 1
    end
    if @user.user_data.update_attributes(params[:user_data])
      if wrong_data
        flash[:Error] = t "generic.messages.error.wrong_data"
        redirect_to :back and return
      end
      flash[:Success] = t "generic.messages.success.account_updated"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:Error] = @user.user_data.errors.full_messages.join(".<br>")
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

and following view:

```
<div id="ProfileEditForm" class="ContentBorders">

  <h1 class="FormsHeading"><%= t @title %></h1>
  <div class="FormsSpacing">

  <%= form_for(@user.user_data, :html => { :id => "UpdateUserForm", :class => "EditForms"}, :url => {:action => 'update_personalization'}) do |f| %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="FormsMargins <%= key %>"><%=raw value + "." %></div>
  <% end %>

      <div class="Field"><div class="LabelInline"><%= t "generic.site.first_name" %>:</div>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :id => "EditFirstName", :class => "Rounded5", :maxlength => "30" %></div>

      <div class="Field"><div class="LabelInline"><%= t "generic.site.last_name" %>:</div>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :id => "EditLastName", :class => "Rounded5", :maxlength => "30" %></div>

      <div class="Field DateSelection"><div class="LabelInline"><%= t "generic.site.birthdate" %>:</div>
        <%= date_select("user_data", "birthdate", :start_year => 1901, :end_year => 2011, :include_blank => true) %>
      </div>

      <div class="Field GenderSelection"><div class="LabelInline"><%= t "generic.site.gender" %>:</div>
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, "0", :id => "EditGenderMale" %> <span><%= t "generic.site.male" %></span>
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, "1", :id => "EditGenderFemale" %> <span><%= t "generic.site.female" %></span>
      </div>

      <div class="Field EducationSelection"><div class="LabelInline"><%= t "generic.site.educational_level" %>:</div>
        <%= f.select :education_level, options_for_select({
          " " => 0, (t "generic.site.education_levels.first") => 1, (t "generic.site.education_levels.second") => 2,
          (t "generic.site.education_levels.third") => 3, (t "generic.site.education_levels.fourth") => 4,
          (t "generic.site.education_levels.fifth") => 5, (t "generic.site.education_levels.sixth") => 6,
          (t "generic.site.education_levels.seventh") => 7 }, @user.user_data.education_level) %>
      </div>

      <div class="Action"><%= f.submit (t "generic.forms.update_data"), :id => "EditSubmit", :class => "ProfileEditAction Shadow1 Rounded5 AcceptButtonsBorder" %></div>

  <% end %>

  </div>

</div>
<%= render :partial => 'profile_panel' %>
```

Now. The problem is with date_select method. Each of form field works properly (data from database fills them up), except that which was generated from data_select.

If I select some proper data, and click update button, then it saves that proper data to the db. Problem comes with the moment, when it is generated, and it doesn't come with any values (it's always empty when loaded).

Any ideas, how can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe...

you have:

```
<%= date_select("user_data", "birthdate", :start_year => 1901, :end_year => 2011, :include_blank => true) %>
```

you need:

```
<%= f.date_select("user_data", "birthdate", :start_year => 1901, :end_year => 2011, :include_blank => true) %>
```

**just put the "f"**

```
<%= f.date_select ...
```